# Minimum amount of queries to get several products in woocommerce

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

Looking into performance for Wordpress using Woocommerce and i'm looking for benchmarks.

Lets say we have a page that queries 16 products, all from different categories. Each product has a few different methods

Whats the minimum number of queries that wordpress has to do to fetch 16 posts from a post type?

Currently, I've got a page that is running 400+ queries to pull back all the data for these products. There's a great deal of customisation with them, so I know it can be improved.

But if products and meta can be called in as few as possible, I'm sure we can refactor along the same practices

Comment: I'm guessing '1'.

Comment: ha, `SELECT * FROM *.*` and just parse everything

Answer (score 0):

I think the best practise for this case is post__in parameter.
You gather all 400 ID-s to one single array. Then use get_posts (or WP_QUERY) with post_type=>product, post__in=>array($gathered_product_ids) arguments.

Comment: But where are the IDs coming from? Would there be a query to fetch those IDs, then running the query?

Comment: But i thought you already knew where were they coming from. If you don't know and all off them are independent queries - then the best way is to use cache plugin or cusom caching code (f.e. saving data in WP transients).

Comment: Another way is using pseudo-caching via ID-s. After each wp query you can save returned ID-s, then gather all of them and save somewhere in wp_options table. Since second request using those ID-s.  But this way requires serious editing in PHP structure of you theme. So the only comfortable way is using cache plugin or custom caching code method.

Comment: I'm completely fine with restructuring everything. In fact, it's whats needed. i'm using transients at the moment to store IDs in queries, but then it's queries within the query that's getting me – Custom meta, taxonomies etc. that belong to products also need to be fetched. Fetching the product only contains further IDs for those objects

Comment: now it is clear. 
using cache plugin is the only normal way for this case. 
if after each cache clear first request works slowly - then you can just build minutely Cron Job with "php /path/index.php" command which will take over "first slow loading" and public visitors would not face slow loading . You can also set highest memory_limit for php-cli/php.ini to let it finishing jobs fast.

Comment: It's true, you can cache, and in most cases we do pre-warm the cache on first load. But the root of the problem is the amount of queries hitting the database. I'm talking 1.3 seconds of db time before ttfb :/